# Why does Regexp.ReplaceAllString escape some characters in the replacement string?

Tags: go

With the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
)

var namedMatch = regexp.MustCompile("\\{([^}]+)\\}")

func main() {
    example := regexp.QuoteMeta("/book/{author-id}/{book-id}")
    new_path := namedMatch.ReplaceAllString(example, `(?P<$1>[^/]+)`)

    regexp.MustCompile(new_path)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hEhZIyZLtHn)

we get the following panic:

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`/book/\(?P<author-id\>[^/]+)/\(?P<book-id\>[^/]+)`): error parsing regexp: unexpected ): `/book/\(?P<author-id\>[^/]+)/\(?P<book-id\>[^/]+)`

goroutine 1 [running]:
regexp.MustCompile(0xc000110040, 0x31, 0x1f)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/regexp/regexp.go:311 +0x157
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox229373954/prog.go:13 +0x8b
```

Why is the replacement string `\(?P<author-id\>[^/]+)` and `\(?P<book-id\>[^/]+)` get escaped like this? Shouldn't `Regexp` put the string as-is? How do I work around this in order to have a valid regular expression in the replacement?

Comment: Do `fmt.Println(example)` to see that the `\ ` character is already there. `regexp.QuoteMeta` returns you a valid regexp, then you break it with your replacement, since you in your replacement only replace `{a\}`

Comment: @zerkms I see, that makes sense. It seems like the issue is my inability to remove `\{` instead of just `{`

Comment: @zerkms oh, nvm, adding an extra pair of \\ did the trick: `regexp.MustCompile("\\\\{([^}]+)\\\\}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @zerkms, turns out the regexp was wrong. Instead of:

```
var namedMatch = regexp.MustCompile("\\{([^}]+)\\}")
```

It should be:

```
var namedMatch = regexp.MustCompile("\\\\{([^}]+)\\\\}")
```

thus the regexp will replace the escaped curly keys correctly.

Comment: Instead of double escaping you might have used the backtick string literals: `\` `